# Understanding why some Galois extension over $\mathbb{Q}_2$ has Galois group $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}_2$ and $d_2 = 3x^4 + 12 x^2 + 4x - 4 \in K[x]$. Let $L_0$ be the splitting field of $d_2$ and let $\alpha \in L_0$ be a root of $d_2$. Let $L/L_0$ be the quadratic extension obtained by
$\delta := (1+2\alpha + \alpha^3)^{1/2}$.

In this [paper](https://icerm.brown.edu/materials/Slides/sp-f15-offweeks/Stable_reduction_and_computation_of_bad_reduction_Euler_factors_-_part_I_%5D_Irene_Bouw,_University_of_Ulm.pdf) (more precisely in Example 4.2), **it is claimed that the Galois group of $L/K$ is $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ and I have trouble understanding why**.

I know that by the theory of Galois groups of quartic polynomials, it is $\operatorname{Gal}(L_0/K) = S_4$. And obviously, it is $\operatorname{Gal}(L/L_0) = C_2$. But $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ is quite a big group (has order $48$) and I have problems understanding where the generators of $L/K$ (i.e. the roots of $d_2$, and $\delta$) map. I know that $\delta \mapsto -\delta$ generates $\operatorname{Gal}(L/L_0) = C_2$ and $\phi_1,\phi_2 \in \operatorname{Gal}(L_0/K)$ with $\phi_1(\alpha_i) = \alpha_{i+1 \mod 4}$ and $\phi_2(\alpha_1) = \alpha_2$, $\phi(\alpha_2) = \alpha_1$, $\phi(\alpha_j) =\alpha_j$ for $j=3,4$ generate $\operatorname{Gal}(L_0/K)$ (here, $\alpha=\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_4$ are the four distinct roots of $d_2$).

Could you help me explaining the elements of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$?

Comment: Is this not more or less equivalent to asking why all the elements $1+2\alpha_i+\alpha_i^3$ have square roots in $L$ and how to write them all in terms of $\alpha_i$s and $\delta$. This feels like a very special property of the polynomial $d_2$ (or the field $L$). May be it was reverse enginereed? First construct an extension with Galois group $GL_2(\Bbb{F}_3)$ and then find the subfield of invariants of the center?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Could you please explain to me why the subfield of invariants of the center matters here?

Comment: $GL_2(\Bbb{F}_3)/\langle -I_2\rangle\simeq S_4$, but I'm no longer sure that isvery relevant. My next guess is that the authors know a lot about what kind of elements of $L_0$ have square roots in $L_0$. Residing above 2-adic numbers there may be a useful general description. Wish I knew what it is :-(

Comment: Only now I looked at your link. They say they used Sage to get the Galois group, so I am not going to compete with that. Undoubtedly a lot follows from (or is buried in) the preceding material. At some point I calculated a few Neron models of elliptic curves for fun, but that was a long time ago, and this stuff is above my paygrade, sorry.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I downvote because the OP didn't say this is the extension generated by the 3-torsion of $E/\Bbb{Q}_2:y^2=x^3+2x+1$. So it suffices to show that $[L:\Bbb{Q}_2] = 48$ to get that its Galois group is automatically $GL_2(\Bbb{F}_3)$.

Comment: @reuns I agree that essential parts of the question were left out. Ribbity, the way you posed the question framed it in such a way that it should be solvable starting from the quartic alone. The extra structure in the article is very relevant.

Comment: Sorry for causing trouble. I thought I just included the parts which understand because I was afraid of messing up the assumptions for my question.